# Self-Signing library jars and setting sandbox permissions in IntelliJ JavaFX artifacts

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, javafx

IntelliJ has a very nifty way to build javafx deployable jars, but I seem to be struggling with Java security.

1) To avoid ugly "this application is unsigned" warnings I want to self-sign my javafx jars. IntelliJ allows that, helpfully, but it doesn't sign the library jars that come with it so that I end up with runtime exceptions due to mismatch signing. How to fix that?

2) The manifest file created in the jar doesn't have the Permission attribute, this is fundamental to avoid another barrage of security warning messages. My original manifest actually has `Permissions: sandbox` set, but I think the artifact-building procedure ignores it.